# Does the resource modifier sw<N>dp work in the manifest

Tags: android

I want to set an attribute of the app element in the manifest to a boolean defined in the resources. And I want the value of the boolean to be different for phones and tablets.

The manifest:

```
    <application
        android:largeHeap="@bool/use_large_heap"
...
```

My resource in the values folder:

```
<resources>
    <bool name="use_large_heap">false</bool>
</resources>
```

My resource in the values-sw720dp folder:

```
<resources>
    <bool name="use_large_heap">true</bool>
</resources>
```

This however does not work. The largeHeap option is not enabled on my 10" tablet. I have tried the exact same approach with the API version modifier v17 and that works fine.

So, **does the sw modifier not work when using it in the manifest?**

*P.S.: I know about the drawbacks of largeHeap and have considered it's use carefully, this is not part of this question.*